# Which topic should I publish path to?

Tags: ros, path, planner, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I am trying to implement a global path planner to Turtlebot 2 using ROS navigation.
Now I can get the initial position, goal position and map data these three for path planning.
And I am trying to verify my output.
I wrote a simple TALKER to send path to topic `/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/global_plan`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");

  ros::NodeHandle p;
  ros::Publisher path_pub = p.advertise<nav_msgs::Path>("move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/global_plan", 1000);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(1);

  nav_msgs::Path gui_path;
  geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose;
  std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped> plan;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
      pose.pose.position.x = i;
      pose.pose.position.y = -i;
      pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
      pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
      pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
      pose.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
      pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
      plan.push_back(pose);
    }

gui_path.poses.resize(plan.size());

if(!plan.empty()){
      gui_path.header.frame_id = 'map';
      gui_path.header.stamp = plan[0].header.stamp;
}

for(unsigned int i=0; i < plan.size(); i++){
      gui_path.poses[i] = plan[i];
}

while (1){
  path_pub.publish(gui_path);
  ros::spinOnce();
  loop_rate.sleep();
}
  return 0;
}
```

I can rostopic echo `move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/global_plan` and get path like this:

```
header: 
  seq: 10
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: ''
poses: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs: 0
      frame_id: ''
    pose: 
      position: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
      orientation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
        w: 1.0
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs: 0
      frame_id: ''
    pose: 
      position: 
        x: 1.0
        y: -1.0
        z: 0.0
      orientation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
        w: 1.0
```

But the robot in Rviz is not moving.
Is my method wrong? Which topic should I use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197713/which-topic-should-i-publish-path-to?/) by [Tixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/20747/tixiao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2014-11-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) on 2016-01-12**:
is your path appearing in Rviz? I am trying to do something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

global planners for the ROS navigation stack are implemented as plugins for move_base; not as standalone nodes. This allows for better sharing of maps between different parts of the planner, for example. The path topics that are published from the global planner are for visualization and debugging purposes only.

If you want to implement your own global planner, there is a recently published a tutorial on the subject: http://www.ros.org/news/2014/11/new-tutorials-adding-a-global-path-planner-as-plugin-in-ros.html

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2014-11-19**:
@ahendrix: Please note that Clearpath didn't write this particular tutorial (though in our opinion, it's very well written).

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-19**:
@Ryan : you are entirely correct. I have no idea why I thought that was a Clearpath tutorial.